# MS Access 2016 - Retaining default text

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm building a report generator in [ms-access](/questions/tagged/ms-access) using exported transactions from Xero accounting.

It includes emailing reports to users.  I have a default `Body Text` for the email, but would like it to be editable by the user (rather than code change).

I can hard-code this using [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) but I would like the user to be able to edit and save it ,so it's available the next time [ms-access](/questions/tagged/ms-access) is opened.

How can Access save this information from one session to the next?

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with a memo field.  Use that as the source for the "body text".

Comment: Thanks GeeFlo, I think this is where my problem is.

Comment: Thanks @GeeFlo,  <br/> I think this is where my understanding is limited. It would be a table with a single record and I would need to be able to access this from a form to both retrieve it and save it.  <br/> I can see how the text could be edited but when the data is to be used by the 'emailing' routine how does link this field in the table?

Comment: Create the table with a unique index that references the email. Use this table as the recordsource for your form or look up recordsets and how to read and write from them